# 3 dimensional equivalent to tilemaps in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am looking for a 3 dimensional equivalent of tilemaps in unity. I built Tetris in 2D in Unity and used tilemaps for most of the functionalities of the game, meaning all movements and rotations. Now I would like to build Tetris in 3D and wonder if there is an equivalent to tilemaps that I could use to build the game.
If there is not, could you recommend something else?

Comment: There is not builtin equivalent unfortunatley.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, do you have any idea what alternative approach I could use ?

Comment: Not particularly, other than suggesting looking for some tutorials on how to create a 3d grid. It's not particularly difficult. Or perhaps there are some assets on the asset store. Come back and ask another question if you get stuck!

Comment: I'll throw in "voxels" as the buzzword of the day.

Comment: If you really want to use Unity's Tilemap system, you could still use it to track the tile position like you would in your 2D tetris, and programatically render 3D models in place of the tiles. I would recommend making your own 3D tile system though. :)